# VBA and Oracle Database universal connection

Tags: excel, vba, oracle

I am trying to connect to oracle database using vba, but I could not make it work properly.
The code is working perfect with some kind of tables, but with some will give me an error `13 type mismatch` and sometimes `3021 bof or eof is true`

the mismatch is on: `mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)`

I have no idea why this is happening.
Also I would like to say that this is my first time  with oracle and vba.

my code so far:

```
Sub Load_data()
        Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
        Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

     cn.Open ( _
    "Provider=*****; User ID = ****; Password = ****; Data Source = *****")

        Dim i As Long
        For i = 1 To 20
            Load_data_into_sheet Sheets("Sheet1"), "COLLABNAME" & i, cn
        Next

        cn.Close

    End Sub

   Private Sub Load_data_into_sheet(ws As Worksheet, CollabName As String, cn As ADODB.Connection)
        ws.Select
        Dim rs As ADODB.recordSet
        Dim col As Integer
        Dim row As Integer
        Dim Query As String
        Dim mtxData As Variant


        Set rs = New ADODB.recordSet

    rs.Open "select * from ZAR01", cn
    With ws
            col = 0
             'First Row: names of columns
            Do While col < rs.Fields.Count
                .Cells(1, col + 1) = rs.Fields(col).Name
                col = col + 1
            Loop


            mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)
            .Range("A2").Resize(UBound(mtxData, 1) - LBound(mtxData, 1) + 1, UBound(mtxData, 2) - LBound(mtxData, 2) + 1) = mtxData




        End With
        rs.Close

'adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText Or adAsyncExecute
    End Sub
```

Comment: If your query returns no records then `rs.EOF` will be true, so you need to test for that before trying to access the recordset.  For type mismatch it's difficult if you don't tell us which line that occurs on.

Comment: @TimWilliams sorry for that ! the type mismatch is always on `mtxData = Application.Transpose(rs.GetRows)`

Comment: Try splitting that up into two lines: `mtxData = rs.GetRows` then `mtxData = Application.Transpose(mtxData)`

Comment: @TimWilliams I have tried it and I got the same error t `mtxData = Application.Transpose(mtxData)` so I deleted this line from the code and it worked, somehow. I have no idea if its correct or not

Comment: I would tend to use `.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rs` since you don't need to worry about transposing the output

Comment: @TimWilliams thanks, that helped me a lot, but now sometimes I am getting `error-2147467259 (80004005) not enough memory ` is this because the chart is too big?

Comment: How many rows/columns are you pulling back?  Do you need the entire table in Excel?

Comment: @TimWilliams I just need few columns from that table.  At the very beginning the numbers of rows  was same as excel limit but somehow I managed to reduce it to 100251 rows and for now I am not getting that error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.
Hope someone will find it usefull

```
Sub OracleLocalConnect()
  Dim RecordSet As New ADODB.RecordSet
  Dim con As New ADODB.Connection
  Dim ExcelRange As Range
  Dim SQLStr As String
  
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  con.ConnectionString = "Provider=****; User ID = ****; Password = ****; Data Source = ****"
  
  con.Open
  Set RecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

  SQLStr = "SELECT * FROM WIN1 WHERE (nvl(win1cmfg,' ') <> 'C' and nvl(win1scfg,' ') <> 'C' and win1rcls = '00' and win1rsts = '0' )"
  

  RecordSet.Open SQLStr, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
  
  Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
  Set ExcelRange = ws.Range("A2")
  ExcelRange.CopyFromRecordset RecordSet
  
  RecordSet.Close
  con.Close
Exit Sub

End Sub
```